# How do I add cells together on OS X numbers app

Tags: macos, numbers

What format should the cell be? This can not be added and only gives a exclamation mark - "the formula contains a syntax error.
OS X and numbers v3.5.3

[image]

Comment: There are iOS versions of numbers and OS X versions of numbers. We can help if you edit these details into the post. The cell needs to contain an actual number and the steps to check and change that vary. Or you could use a function to convert strings to numbers, again that depends on the version.

Comment: Your screenshot shows adding two numbers, not cells.  What do you really need?  How to sum numbers or sum cells?

Answer (score 2):

The error at the bottom of your screenshot is from a previous entry. The Result bar does not update as you type—it updates when the cell contents changes. There's nothing wrong with that formula. Press Enter to enter the formula into the cell.

[image]

As for adding cells: whilst in formula edit mode, click the cell to insert its reference into the current cursor location, and use the standard syntax (*something*+*something*).

Answer (score 0):

[gagarside's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/204327/120171) is the correct answer.

To take this a step further, you could use the `SUM` function.

To sum values *hard coded* (like in your original post):

[image: Hard code SUM fuction]

To sum values in *cells* (more dynamic as one can change single values easily):

[image]